# PHP reports with pivot table capabilities

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-4, reporting, mondrian

I am trying to develop a reporting module, with excel-like pivot tables capability. That is, users can change the report view point, aggregate, drill down, filter,.. on the fly.

I have failed to find a reporting platform in php, something like jasper reports, crystal reports and openi. There are solutions like reportico, but not up to the standard.

Among the options I am currently exploring is using Mondrian OLAP Engine. I am not certain about the start point, so would appreciate feedback if anyone has tried using same. Would also love to listen to anything else you have to suggest.

My application is PHP (Laravel 4) + Postgres

Comment: If you liked JasperReports, you can try its implementation on PHP, PHPJasperXML, you can get it from here: http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML, however, i'm not sure it will fit the bill as it mainly displays static reports.

Comment: thanks @MiguelGarcia, but I am looking into dynamic reports. do let me know if you know of any.